# Construct maximal ideal in multivariate polynomial ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, polynomials, ring-theory, ideals, maximal-and-prime-ideals

I would like to see a constructive proof of the existence of maximal ideal in multivariate polynomial ring over $\mathbb C$. I know there are proofs for more general rings using axiom of choice. But I think a constructive proof can give us more insights. The multivariate polynomial ring is a very conrete example, so I believe there should be some conrete proofs (maybe even for the case where the field is not algebraically closed).

To be more precise, suppose there is a proper ideal $I$ of $\mathbb C[x_1, x_2, \cdots,x_n]$, and we know $I$ is generated by finite elements $f_1,f_2,\cdots f_k$. **How can we explicitly construct a maximal ideal that contains $I$?**

I have found a post [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/258554/maximal-ideals-in-multivariate-polynomial-rings), I don't know whether it asked the same question. In [this post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/26497/maximal-ideals-in-the-ring-kx1-xn) the exact form of maximal ideals in $\mathbb C[x_1, x_2, \cdots,x_n]$ is given, I believe it can help (though I don't know whether this result requires the existence of maximal ideals).

Thank you very much if you would like to help.

Comment: There's a correspondence to the geometry.  You need to find an $n$-tuple $(a_1,\ldots,a_n)$ such that $f_1(a_1,\ldots,a_n)=0,\ldots,f_k(a_1,\ldots,a_n)=0$ simultaneously and then the maximal ideal $(x_1-a_1,\ldots,x_n-a_n)$ contains $I$.

Answer (score 1):

By Hilbert's Nullstellensatz, we know that maximal ideals of $\mathbb{C}[X_1,...,X_n]$ are exactly the ideals of the form $(X_1-a_1,...,X_n-a_n)$ for $a_1,...,a_n \in \mathbb{C}$.
Suppose $I=\langle f_1,...,f_k \rangle $. Then if we find $a_1,...,a_n$ in $\mathbb{C}$ such that $f_1(a_1,...,a_n)=f_2(a_1,...,a_n)=...=f_k(a_1,...,a_n)=0$, we know by polynomial division that $f_1,...,f_k \in (X_1-a_1,...,X_n-a_n)$ and therefore $I\subset (X_1-a_1,...,X_n-a_n)$ which is maximal.
So all one has to do is find a n-tuple $(a_1,...,a_n)$ in $\mathbb{C}^n$ that is a root of all the $f_i$.